# loop string in each object to one string

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures

How to loop string in each object add to one string like below result?
I need to add each variable `this_encode` to one string, how to do it?

`result: '<img src=""><iframe></iframe><img src="">'`

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].file_type == 0) {
        var this_encode = '<img src="' + obj[key].file_name + obj[key].file_format + '">';
    } else if(obj[key].file_type == 1) {
        var this_encode = '<iframe width="150" height="100" src="'+obj[key].file_embed_url +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
}
```

obj

```
file_embed_url: ""  
file_format: "jpg"  
file_name: "53b21c90dded9"  
file_sequence: "0"  
file_type: "0"  
gallery_id: "1"  
id: "138"  

file_embed_url: "//www.youtube.com/embed/-x6jzKpqeuw"  
file_format: ""  
file_name: ""  
file_sequence: "1"  
file_type: "1"  
gallery_id: "1"  
id: "139"  

...
```

Comment: What is the data for `obj`?

Comment: declare your string outside the loop and then use concatenation to create a single string.

Comment: @jasonscript thanks for reply, can you make a example?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield `obj` is javascript object like above example

Comment: @user1775888 declare `this_encode` *before* you start the `for`. So it would be `var this_encode = '';` then `for (var key in obj) {`. Inside the `for` just replace `var this_encode = ` with `this_encode += `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your `this_encode` variable outside the loop and then use concatenation to create a single string

```
// first initialise your variable as an empty string; can't concatenate to undefined
var this_encode = '';

// Now run your code as before with 2 small differences
//      (1) Remove the var declarations
//      (2) Use += instead of = to indicate that you want to append the following text to the this_encode variable
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].file_type == 0) {
        this_encode += '<img src="' + obj[key].file_name + obj[key].file_format + '">';
    //  ^           ^ see the change here
    //  |
    //  var declartion removed from here (and below)
    } else if(obj[key].file_type == 1) {
        this_encode += '<iframe width="150" height="100" src="'+obj[key].file_embed_url +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        //          ^ and here
    }
}
```